# Mostrar um conjunto de imagens em um novo layout a partir de uma lista

Tags: java, android

Olá,
eu tenho uma classe Activity, que mostra um layout com uma lista de itens, que ao clicar em cada item, mostraria um layout novo (Livros2), com um viewFlipper, porém, cada item da lista deveria mostrar um conjunto de imagens diferentes, só que só mostra o mesmo conjunto de imagens, que está no prórpio Livros2. Onde estou errando?

Classe da lista:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //Arrays de imagens:
        final int livro1[] = {R.drawable.desenho1, R.drawable.desenho2, R.drawable.desenho3};
        int livro2[]={R.drawable.desenho2,R.drawable.desenho1,R.drawable.desenho3};

        final ArrayList<Itens> livros = new ArrayList<Itens>();
        livros.add(new Itens("Livro 1", "Autor 1",livro1));
        livros.add(new Itens("Livro 2", "Autor 2",livro2));
        livros.add(new Itens("Livro 3", "Autor 3",livro1));

        MeuAdapter array = new MeuAdapter (this,livros);
        ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.item);
        lista.setAdapter(array);


        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
               Intent intent = new Intent(Livros.this, Livros2.class);

                startActivity(intent);}


        });
    }
}
```

E a classe que deve ser usada para abrir o array dos livros é a seguinte:

```
public class Livros2 extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button anterior,proxima;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_livros2); 

        int[]imagens ={R.drawable.desenho2,R.drawable.images,R.drawable.desenho3};

        final ViewFlipper trocarImagens = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flip);
        for (int i = 0; i<imagens.length; i++){
        ImageView nova = new ImageView(this);
        nova.setImageResource(imagens[i]);
        trocarImagens.addView(nova);//}

        anterior = findViewById(R.id.voltar);
        anterior.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trocarImagens.showPrevious();
            }
        });
        proxima = findViewById(R.id.avançar);

        proxima.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                trocarImagens.showNext();
            }
        });


}}}
```

Comment: Isabela, a tag da linguagem também é necessária, e por se tratar de android, adicionei a tag java, que á a linguagem que você está trabalhando.

Comment: Ah,ok! Obrigada!!

Comment: Não. Eu errei, desculpa. Agora eu arrumei!